# Muchos Errores al conectar Java con NetBeans con MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy realizando mi primera aplicacion java con Mysql en IDE NETBEANS, y me surgen varios errores al querer correrlos y ya no encuentro como solucionarlos, busque mucha info y pero ya no encuentro mi error. Aclaro que ya agregue el archivo .Jar del JDBC al al Build-Path de mi proyecto.
Muestro mi clase conexionMysql.java:

```
package clientes_crud;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class conexionMysql {
     public static Connection getConector(String servidor,String bd,String user,String pswd) {
        Connection conexion = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crudcliente";
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crudcliente",
                    "root",
                    "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conexion;
    }

    com.mysql.jdbc.Connection conectar() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from
```

nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
}
}

Muestro mi clase frmPanelClientes.java

```
package clientes_crud;


import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.sql.*;

public class frmPanelClientes extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    conexionMysql con= new conexionMysql();
    Connection cn=con.conectar();

    public frmPanelClientes() {
        initComponents();
        mostrardatos();
    }
//Aca estaría(no lo puse ahora) toda la declaración de variables y los que respecta al diseño de las ventanas....

    private void mostrardatos() {
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        modelo.addColumn("id");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre y apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Dirección");
        modelo.addColumn("Email");
        modelo.addColumn("Teléfono");
        modelo.addColumn("Estado civil");
        jtabledatos.setModel(modelo);
        String consultasql = "select*from clientes";
        String data[]=new String[6];
        
        Statement st;
        try {
            st=(Statement) cn.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(consultasql); 
            while(rs.next()){ 
                data[0]=rs.getString(1);
                data[1]=rs.getString(2);
                data[2]=rs.getString(3);
                data[3]=rs.getString(4);
                data[4]=rs.getString(5);
                data[5]=rs.getString(6);
                modelo.addRow(data);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error al mostrar datos " + e);
        }
        
    }
```

si me pueden ayudar, se los agradezo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! muchos errores.. que errores?

Comment: y los errores cuales son?

Comment: El `Class.forName()` hace muchísimo tiempo que no es necesario. Si estás usando un tutorial, intenta buscar uno más actualizado.